# How to convert a list of hour and minutes strings to datetime without adding year using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list, datetime

I have dataframe indexed by datetime and I want to make a dictionary with hours and minutes. For that matter I do the following:

```
lista = list(set(perfis.index.strftime('%H:%M').tolist()))
```

which returns

```
['01:00', '17:00', '19:00', '21:00', '19:15', '07:15', '18:30', '05:45', '15:30',..., '04:00', '11:30']
```

Now I want to order it and for that matter I want to recovert it to datetime:

```
pd.to_datetime(lista, format='%H:%M')
```

Which gives me

```
DatetimeIndex(['1900-01-01 01:00:00', '1900-01-01 17:00:00',
               '1900-01-01 19:00:00', '1900-01-01 21:00:00',
               '1900-01-01 19:15:00', '1900-01-01 07:15:00',
               '1900-01-01 18:30:00', '1900-01-01 05:45:00',
               '1900-01-01 15:30:00', ..., '1900-01-01 11:30:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

However, I just want the hours and minutes and if I use `time` I get

```
[datetime.time(1, 0) datetime.time(17, 0) datetime.time(19, 0)
 datetime.time(21, 0) datetime.time(19, 15) datetime.time(7, 15)
 datetime.time(18, 30) datetime.time(5, 45) datetime.time(15, 30)
 datetime.time(11, 30)]
```

How can I get a list of ordered datetime entries only with hours and minutes?

Comment: Have you tried sorting the last list?

Comment: @gshpychka however the last list returns  a datetime object and I just want the something like '00:15'.

Comment: So you would use `strftime` to generate a formatted string from a datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just sort the list using `sorted`:

```
lista = sorted(list(set(perfis.index.strftime('%H:%M').tolist())))
```